# In Javascript does the variable is captured by closure even if it is not used?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

Maybe this is a stupid question but I couldn't find an answer on it. Assume we have code like this:

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Billy';
  var unusedVariable = 'unused';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
```

As far as I understand, in this example a variable `name` will be collected when there won't be references on it, so it will live while the closure `myFunc` lives. But will `unusedVariable` live while `myFunc` lives? In other words, does displayName() 'captures' this `unusedVariable` even if it is unused?

Comment: Because even if it is unused, it is in the memory of the outerscope.

Comment: It's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. All the variables created in "makeFunc" scope will exist in the closure, irrespective of whether used or not. To be precise, that is what closure means. Inside "displayName", you 'can' (not "must') refer to both those variables.

Comment: It's not that simple. Modern engines will optimize away unreferenced variables if possible.

Comment: Yes. You are right. i verified with the firebug. the unused variables are excluded from the closure scope. Only the used ones are retained in the scope. Maybe the latest browsers do this for better memory management and performance.

Comment: Yes, modern engines have many such optimizations. In your test, put an `eval()` call in the returned function that evals input from a text field, and I'll bet all the variables will be retained.